# InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' at invalidPipeArgumentError

Tags: html, angular, firebase

I want to get some data from database
Here is my service

```
  export class CategoryService {
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }
  getCategories(){
  return this.db.list('/categories'); 
  }
```

$Component code

```
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {

  categories$;

  constructor(categoryService: CategoryService) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
   }
```

$here is my html

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="category">Category</label>  
      <select id="category" class="form-control">
      <option value=""> </option>
      <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.$key">
      {{c.name}}
      </option>
      </select>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase libraries return promises. Make them return observables.

```js
import { from } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class CategoryService {
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }
  getCategories(){
  return from(this.db.list('/categories')); 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me because a syntax error show up when try to import 'from'

Comment: @MateiEmil yes I added an unecessary `@`, sorry, removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these code it should work

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from '@angular/fire/database';
import {from} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CategoryService {
   constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

 getCategories() {
   return from(this.db.list('/categories').valueChanges());
 }

}
```

Comment: Appreciate you that you answered an old question which is still looking for the correct answer, but it will be helpful for OP and others if you provide some explanation. Like why you think this would work, what changes you made & why, etc